# Correct way to make comparison based on other models fields

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

```py
for line in invoice.invoice_line_ids:
        if line.sale_line_ids:
            if line.sale_line_ids.qty_avl_stock >= line.sale_line_ids.product_uom_qty:
                        term = _('At warehouse')
```

in a proforma invoice, I want to check sale_order_line fields that is related to  invoice_line.

In account.invoice.line I found a relation to sale.order.line it's `sale_line_ids` field. my goal is to make some checking in related `sale_order_line` but is this a good way to do? or maybe I should do a search on sale.order.line model?
Because `sale_line_ids` field is many2many and probably there can be more than one record and if that is the case i will get an error here.

**UPDATE for bounty**

Basically, I need check order_line qty_avl_stock and product_uom_qantity that is related to invoice_line. But I don't know how is the best way to relate sale_order_line to invoice_line, or maybe there are other solutions?

```
class SaleOrerLine(self)

 qty_avl_stock = fields.float("Quantity availible stock")
```

Comment: if not all([ x.qty_avl_stock >=x.product_uom_qty  ==  for x in line.sale_line_ids]):

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please provide your code for the field `qty_avl_stock`

Comment: updatedmy question